# How can we Hash a Symmetric Cryptographic Key for Windows Store Apps?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, cryptography, windows-store-apps

The hashing technique present for Windows.Security Library is as follows.

```
HashAlgorithmProvider Hash_Sha256 = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha256);
IBuffer HashedDerivedKey = Hash_Sha256.HashData(DerivedPrimaryKey);
```

Is there a possibility where I can directly hash a Symmetric Cryptographic Key.

That is, directly hash the 'key' as mentioned below.

```
CryptographicKey key = aesCbcPkcs7.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(32));
```

Comment: Any reason why you need that specific hashing / encrypting? Because in wp8 RT there is also a PasswordVault to store stuff that needs to be secure...

Comment: @Depechie what happens when streams of data have to be secured like file contents ?

Comment: Ok that would be a valid point not to use the password vault :) purpose for it are small chunks of data

Comment: Hashing is a one-way process.  Once you hash the key you cannot recover it unless you keep a separate unhashed copy elsewhere.  Are you talking about a key-generation process, rather than hashing?

Comment: @rossum  

The idea is to provide a dual layer of security where the cryptographic key in use is encrypted and stored for encryption and decryption. 

But the windows library for store applications is restrictive as it does not allow us to perform any action on a Cryptographic Key. 

We have an export key method but it seems to be working only for asymmetric algorithms.